# Связь элементов в двух массива (reference)

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio

Есть массив `results = [1, 3, 5, 1, 8, 5, 0, 6]`, берём, например, массив первых двух значений `results2 = [results[0], results[1]]`. Как сделать так, чтобы изменяя массив `results2`, изменялось значение в массиве `results`

Т.е. результат должен быть таким:

```
var results = [1, 3, 5, 1, 8, 5, 0, 6]
var results2 = [results[0], results[1]]
results2[1] - 1
```

Вывод (см. на 2-й элемент массива):

```
results = [1, 2, 5, 1, 8, 5, 0, 6]
```

Comment: А как вы пробовали сделать? Можно ваш код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы храните в массивах объекты типа `struct` (как в случае с `Int`), то нужно для них сделать обертку в виде класса для обращения по ссылкам, а не копирования

Пример

```
class IntWrapper : CustomStringConvertible {
    
    private var value = 0
    
    var description: String {
        String(value)
    }

    init(_ value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    func setValue(_ value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
}

var results = [IntWrapper(1), IntWrapper(3)]
var results2 = [results[0], results[1]]
results2[1].setValue(999)

print(results, results2)
```

Вывод:

```
[1, 999] [1, 999]
```